# Why does Rx Observable.Subscribe block my thread?

Tags: system.reactive, observable

Hello there' I've tried out one of the 101 Rx examples:

```
    static IEnumerable<int> GenerateAlternatingFastAndSlowEvents()
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (i > 1000)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            yield return i;
            Thread.Sleep(i++ % 10 < 5 ? 500 : 1000);
        }
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        var observable = GenerateAlternatingFastAndSlowEvents().ToObservable().Timestamp();
        var throttled = observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(750));

        using (throttled.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Value, x.Timestamp)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to unsubscribe");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I don't understand why the line "Press any key to unsubscribe" never shows. My understanding was subscribing is asynchronous, you subscribe and it immedietly returns. What am I missing that causes my main thread to block?

Answer (score 7):

The blocking is caused by a combination of your enumerable looping on `while (true)` and `IEnumerable<T>.ToObservable()` extension methods defaulting to `CurrentThreadScheduler`.

If you supply `Scheduler.TaskPool` (or `Scheduler.ThreadPool` in pre-.NET 4) to an overload of `ToObservable`, you should see the behavior you're expecting (though it won't call your subscriber on the main thread, FYI).

Having said that, I think you'll find your combination of `Thread.Sleep` and `Throttle` will work as you expect. You're probably better off creating a custom observable that uses a scheduler to schedule your delays.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Richard.

The implementation for `.ToObservable()` looks like this:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> ToObservable<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    return source.ToObservable<TSource>(Scheduler.CurrentThread);
}
```

It's calling the `.ToObservable(IScheduler)` overload with `Scheduler.CurrentThread` and since you're using `.Sleep(...)` to cause the delays the observable has to complete before the code can go beyond the `.Subscribe(...)` method. Just think in terms of what would this code behave like if it all ran on a single thread (which it is.)

To get around this you can use the task pool or thread pool schedulers as Richard suggests, but I think you have a more fundamental issue with your code. And that is that you're using "old school" thread sleeping and not relying on Rx methods instead.

Try this to generate your observable:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .GenerateWithTime(0, i => i <= 1000, i => i + 1,
            i => i, i => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i % 10 < 5 ? 500 : 1000))
        .Timestamp();
```

`GenerateWithTime(...)` does everything that your `GenerateAlternatingFastAndSlowEvents` method did, but it creates the observable directly and does it using the `Scheduler.ThreadPool` under the hood so you don't need to specify any schedulers.

Comment: So using .ToObservable Creates an Observable that runs on current thread, and therefore its the main thread that runs the Generate.. method. So Subscribe doesn't block the thread, because it is busy executing the observable. So how is it that if I use SubscribeOn and passing ThreadPoolScheduler, that I see the message "Press any key to unsubscribe"? If my thread is busy execting the observable, it shouldn't matter where I subscribe.

Comment: @Eldar - As soon as you use `SubscribeOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)` then the subscription and the observer are running on a new thread so the `Subscribe` method returns immediately and you'll see your message. It's only if your observable schedules using the `CurrentThread` scheduler that your `Subscribe` method and the observer will run on the current thread.